# Quantity Increments setting is not working in Minicart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, mini-cart, validation

We are using Magento 2.4.3.

For one of the products, we have enabled quantity increments and set 3 in the "Qty increments" setting.

[image]

These settings are working fine on the product detail page and on the shopping cart page. we are able to add 3,6,9 and so on quantities into the cart but this is not working in the mini cart. This means if we have 3 quantities of a product and when we try to update the quantity in the mini cart then it is allowing any quantities. we are able to update the quantity to 4 in a mini cart. the quantity validation is not working in the mini cart.

We do not have any third-party or custom plugins related to mini carts. How can we fix this issue?

Comment: Please check errors log in Console tab of the Browser's Developer tool. If you see any errors, please add them to your post.

Comment: @TuVan We are getting no errors in the Browser console at all. This is why it is hard for us to find the actual cause of this issue.

Comment: This feature should work properly with Magento default. Try to switch to the default luma theme to check if the issue is related to your theme/modules or not.

Comment: @TuVan Already checked in the default luma theme. the issue is present in the luma theme. we tried to find the issue in the third-party module but it didn't help. Is there a way to debug this issue to know where is this coming from? or do we have to disable third-party modules one by one?

Comment: I think you should disable 3rd-party modules by group or disable 3-5-10 modules per time to check instead of disable one by one.

Comment: Hi @ChintanKaneriya we're having the same problem, did you solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @simonthesorcerer, I think the issue was with the third-party extension. we were using pre order extension from BSS and it was conflicting with the default Magento feature.